# How to add json file to specific folder in Google Apps Script?

Tags: json, google-apps-script, google-drive-api, drive

This code working good, but file goes to the root folder. I not found any helpfully in internet...

```
function saveAsJSON() {
  var blob,file,fileSets,obj;
  
  obj = {//Object literal for testing purposes
    key:"value"
  }

/**
 * Creates a file in the users Google Drive
 */
  
  fileSets = {
    title: 'file.json',
    mimeType: 'application/json'
  };
  
  blob = Utilities.newBlob(JSON.stringify(obj), "application/vnd.google-apps.script+json");
  file = Drive.Files.insert(fileSets, blob);
  Logger.log('ID: %s, File size (bytes): %s, type: %s', file.id, file.fileSize, file.mimeType);

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### ANSWER

You need to use the `parents` property in your `fileSets` and put your desired drive folder ID, [as seen from this sample documentation](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/folder#create_a_file_in_a_folder). See this tweaked script below:

### Tweaked Script

```
function saveAsJSON() {
  var blob,file,fileSets,obj;
  
  obj = {//Object literal for testing purposes
    key:"value"
  }

/**
 * Creates a file in the users Google Drive
 */
  
  fileSets = {
    title: 'file.json',
    mimeType: 'application/json',
    parents:[{"id":"THE_FOLDER_ID"}] //Add your FOLDER_ID here
  };
  
  blob = Utilities.newBlob(JSON.stringify(obj), "application/vnd.google-apps.script+json");
  file = Drive.Files.insert(fileSets, blob);
  Logger.log('ID: %s, File size (bytes): %s, type: %s', file.id, file.fileSize, file.mimeType);
}
```

### Sample Demonstration

- The file was saved to my sample `tempFolder`:

> [image]

Comment: @NearEternal I hope this works on your end. Just let me know if there's anything missing.

Comment: Perfect! Now it's working, Thanks!